# How to properly define is-derived-from-view-interface?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

[LWG3549](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3549) proposes that [`view_interface<D>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/view_interface) does not need to inherit [`view_base`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/view), which allows range adaptors to better perform empty base optimization.

In the latest [[range.view]](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.view), the definition of `view` concept has undergone the following changes:

```
template<class T>
  concept view =
    range<T> && movable<T> && enable_view<T>;

template<class T>
inline constexpr bool is-derived-from-view-interface = see below;     // exposition only
template<class T>
  inline constexpr bool enable_view =
    derived_­from<T, view_base> || is-derived-from-view-interface<T>;
```

Where *`is-derived-from-view-interface`* is defined as:

> For a type `T`, *`is-derived-from-view-interface<T>`* is `true` if and only if
> `T` has exactly one public base class `view_­interface<U>` for some type `U`
> and `T` has no base classes of type `view_­interface<V>` for any other
> type `V`.

The definition of this inline variable seems to have the following form:

```
#include <ranges>

template<class D>
concept is_derived_from_view_interface = 
  std::derived_from<D, std::ranges::view_interface<D>>;

static_assert(is_derived_from_view_interface<std::ranges::iota_view<int>>);
```

But `D` does not have to inherit `view_interface<D>`, it can inherit `view_interface<U>` for some an arbitrary type `U`, and we also need to detect whether `D` inherits another `view_interface<V>` where `V` is not equal to `U`.

So, How to properly define this *`is-derived-from-view-interface`*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That wording means "use template argument deduction".

```cpp
template <class D>
void test(view_interface<D>&);

template <class R>
concept is_derived_from_view_interface = requires (R& r){ (test)(r); };
```

Comment: `requires (R& r) { []<class D>(view_interface<D>&){}(r); }` :-)

Comment: Neat! However, I'm not seeing how this handles "exactly one public base class". Am I missing something?

Comment: @Frankv - more than 1 = ambiguous conversion

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Thanks, that makes perfect sense.

Comment: @HTNW - It won't accept a user defined conversion. Only a derived class can match a base template specislisation. User defined conversions are not considered in template argument deduction.